# How are real numbers represented in binary form?

Tags: c#, binary, bit-manipulation

I need to store a number that contains decimal places (ie 1.5) inside a binary file, the problem is that I don't know how to convert the bytes back to a number when I want to read this file, I know that for integers I only have to do this: `byte[0] << 24 | byte[1] << 16 | byte[2] << 8 | byte[3]` for an Int32 in big endian form. What would be the way to do that for a real number?

Comment: Well, I knew about the BitConverter class, but I want to do this for learning purposes only.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsfy6sz9.aspx) class. It contains methods to convert the various basic types to and from byte arrays. That way you don't need to know how the floating-point numbers are represented in binary.

If you do want to know that, I think the wikipedia article on [floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) is a good place to learn about it.

Answer (score -2):

You can't store real numbers as bits. The data that tells the computer if the number is signed or unsigned also tells it what level of sub-integer precision it supports. The computer does a simple division problem.

Comment: "You can't store real numbers as bits"..?  They're nothing *but* bits.  *Everything* in a computer is stored as bits.  This answer makes no sense.